# How can I count unique values corresponding to a break variable with the function aggregate in SPSS?

Tags: spss, aggregation

I guess it is really easy, but I just cannot find the answer myself. The variable that I would like to calculate is the variable "Number_of brands_bought" (see below) and I've tried to use the aggregate function in SPSS with respondent as break variable and Brand as summaries of variables (and then I choose function count). However, it just does not give me the right answer.

Respondent Brand Number_of_brands_bought
1          1      3
1          2      3
1          3      3
1          3      3
2          1      2
2          2      2
3          1      3
3          4      3
3          5      3

Does anybody know what to do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you made sure, that your data set was sorted by the break variable before you tried to aggregate? If not, it might caused the error.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from the description you have provided how the data is stored. It could be stored in one of two ways (possibly others) either:

1) Wide format

2) Long format

Hopefully this link works to my Google drive docs where I have mocked an example of both file structure formats:
[Example Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Mo2R33XwEhUHhrT2tyTG5TTzA/view?usp=sharing)

If the data is in `wide` format, where you have brands (bought) as individual dichotomous variables and one row per respondent then you can simply sum the values 1's indicating whether that brand had been bought (assuming 0=no/1=yes coding i.e. as oppose to 1=yes/2=no coding which sometimes is the case)

```
compute Num_Brands=sum(Bought_Brand01 to Bought_Brand05).
```

Alternatively, given you suggest the need to use aggregate function, perhaps it is that you have the data in `long` format i.e. `respondents` x `brands`. If that is the case then you can derive the sum of brands using aggregate:

The code in SPSS would be:

```
AGGREGATE OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES /BREAK=ID /Num_Brands=sum(Bought).
```